# Topological conjugacy of the logistic map at different parameter values

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-dynamics, discrete-time

I am wondering whether the dynamical systems generated by the discrete 1 dimensional map $g(x;p) = px(1-x)$ (the logistic map) at different values of $p$ are topologically conjugate.

Of course, this would not be the case if we are comparing a chaotic and a stable fixed point regime. But if we compared two regimes that both have a unique period 2 orbit?